# What is Android Service under the hood

Tags: android, android-service

`Android` documentation states that:

A `Service` is **not** a separate process. The `Service` object itself does not imply it is running in its own process; unless otherwise specified, it runs in the same process as the application it is part of.

A `Service` is **not** a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid `Application Not Responding` errors).

Then what is it? How is it implemented under the hood in `Java`, and how does `Linux` system treat it?
`ps -t` shows that it has a different **PID**.

Comment: It's merely a different stateful lifecycle construct. You can request from Android that it keeps track of the started / stopped state a thing. And it will. Also you tell Android that something is in a started state and the application process shouldn't be killed. In return you get a `Context` to use outside of Activities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then what is it?

Um, it's a Java object, just like `Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver`, etc.

> How is it implemented under the hood in java

It's just a Java object. However, like `Activity` and `BroadcastReceiver`, and unlike `Integer` or `TextView`, the Android framework in your process will respond to particular IPC events by instantiating (if needed) and calling methods on the `Service` (e.g., `onStartCommand()` and `onBind()`).

> and how does linux system treat it?

Linux is oblivious to Java objects.

> ps -t shows that it has a different PID

Java objects do not show up in `ps` output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I was confused and used to think of it like a daemon thread or smth. And if I'm not wrong it was introduced like this previously

Comment: @mdavid: A `Service` usually uses threads, as we don't want background work happening on the main application thread (which `onStartCommand()` and kin are called on). Some specific `Service` subclasses will fork a thread for you (e.g., `IntentService`). Beyond that, you fork your own, or use Android APIs that are intrinsically asynchronous (e.g., `MediaPlayer)`.

Comment: I got. I think the term "running service" is misleading and I'm sure I'm not the only one. But if its just an object why people use to think that "running service" drains battery. Or it's about services which are being created after application is being killed?

Comment: @mdavid: "Running service" means it has been started (`startService()`) and not stopped (`stopService()`/`stopSelf()`), or possibly that some other app bound to it and has not yet unbound. "But if its just an object why people use to think that "running service" drains battery" -- the existence of a running service causes Android to keep the app's process around longer and, depending on service behavior, perhaps start a fresh process for the app faster. That's wasteful of RAM but is not necessarily indicative of wasting CPU, battery, etc.